# What if I have an experience not related to programming and still want to include it in my CV?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

When including an experience item in the CV, there is a field called `Technologies` that needs to be completed with at least two tags.

> [image: Technologies]

What if I have an experience not related to programming that I want to include in my CV? There will be no Stack Overflow tags related to it.

Should it be possible to leave the field blank, with no tags?

---

Non programming experience can still be valuable.  Maybe I used to be a lawyer assistant, and now I write code for systems used by other lawyers. You could expand this example for any other area of expertise.

Comment: Is that a new requirement? My CV has one role that has no technologies.

Comment: That's interesting. All I need is a time machine, then.

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula Tags are free-form. You're not limited to SO tags. Per your example you could do legal, briefs, CosmoLex.